# "Invisible" instance methods in Redis gem

Tags: ruby, redis

There are some instance methods on `Redis` class. They are defined in the source code and they work. BUT they don't show up in `Redis#methods` output!

```
require 'redis'

redis = Redis.new # => #<Redis client v3.0.2 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0>
redis.info['redis_version'] # => "2.6.4"

k = 'foo'
redis.setbit k, 1, 1
redis.setbit k, 3, 1
redis.setbit k, 11, 1

redis.bitcount k # => 3

redis.methods.grep(/bit/) # => [:setbit, :getbit]
# no bitcount in the methods!
```

Method definitions: [getbit](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L821), [setbit](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L810), [bitcount](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L844), [bitop](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L856).

From what I can tell, `bitcount`/`bitop` **should** appear in `methods`. But they don't. Any thoughts?

I need them to be listed in methods so that another gem works (it defines proxy methods for redis commands which it gets from `Redis#methods`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The released version of the gem does not define those methods explicitly, you can confirm this by checking your installed source or `redis.method :bitcount`

https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/v3.0.2/lib/redis.rb

They work because the method missing simply passing them on to the redis server blindly.

Comment: Why would they not export the methods? :puzzled:

Comment: I assumed that since this is quite old functionality, it would be present in the latest gem. Turns out I was wrong to assume this.

Comment: I would just ask them to release a new version of the gem. For most gems they will within a day or so.